Azure Read/Write Function App Config
Which is the azure built-in roles are people using for least privilege that enables users to write to function app config?
I think the required action is: Microsoft.Web/sites/config/write
I checked this site and the only built in role containing this action was "Logic Apps Standard Developer"?
